# ASP.NET BOILERPLATE: javascript to call application service

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

ASP.NET BOILERPLATE: I have a table Asset for which I have created AssetApplicationService with base class CRUDAsync;  I have wired up AssetController, & appropriate  DTO's, I am able to retrieve data and show on the  list as similar to user list.
when I click on Create New Asset,I am able to bring the modal dailog as well until now it is all good, I have copied the user\index.js and tailored to call my asset application service from javascript...this is where i am struck

```
var _assetService = abp.services.app.asset;   //line1
var _$modal = $('#AssetCreateModal');
var _$form = _$modal.find('form');
```

line 1 returns me undefined when I debug through alert(_assetService), not sure why...where as abp.services.app.user, role works fine.

Answer (score 1):

AssetApplicationService must be implemented by **IApplicationService**.

```
 public interface IAssetApplicationService  : IApplicationService
 {   

 }
```

---

```
public class AssetApplicationService : IAssetApplicationService  
{   

}
```

- *Note: I've replied your previous question. Please mark the answer as solution if that worked for you.*

Comment: Thanks for  your help, I found the answer, it was my coding issue.